# App Engine file upload and assignment to variable causes memory usage error after serving X requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm uploading images (<10MB each) to a simplified handler (below) to showcase this problem. After serving ~5 requests on an F1 (128MB of ram) instance I run over the memory limit: "Exceeded soft private memory limit with 152.414 MB after servicing 6 requests total"

On an F2 (256MB of ram) instance I get a few more requests in, but not many: "Exceeded soft private memory limit with 258.156 MB after servicing 19 requests total"

Example code:

```
import webapp2
class FileUploader(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def post(self):
    test = self.request.get('file')
    self.response.out.write('hi')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/leak-uploader-example', FileUploader)],
                              debug=True)
```

The text in the logs suggest my application may have a memory leak. It seems like the problem may be with either Python or App Engine garbage collecting after a request is complete. Any suggestions for how to keep my instances from being terminated after only a few requests?

*update* --  I'm seeing the same behavior using webapp framework (instead of webapp2): "Exceeded soft private memory limit with 143.121 MB after servicing 6 requests total"

Comment: Is this the exact code you are using ?  I seriously doubt it's a endemic problem with appengine. Otherwise lots of people would have a problem.  I can upload images all day and don't run out of memory (though I don't use webapp2) but my processing is a lot more complex than you example.

Comment: Right, exact code to reproduce this. Simply accessing the file uploaded is enough to cause the memory leak. I was doing image transforms and uploading to Google Cloud Storage originally but I stripped it down the bare minimum that still had issues. I gave webapp a try and am seeing the same behavior (webapp code added above). How fast are you uploading files to your handler? How big are the files?

Comment: I wasnt suggesting not to use webapp2. More that my experience is not based on webapp2 in the interest of full disclosure. I don't use webapp either.  All my work is typically with pyramid and/or bobo.

Comment: I note you are using old style app definition.  You should try the 2.7 app definition model.

Comment: Thanks for the full disclosure, I definitely wouldn't use webapp in production -- worth a shot to see if the memory leak was still there though. I'm at a loss for next steps to debug further... The terminated requests are somehow still taking up memory!?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, yep the webapp code skeleton was taken out of an old project. Definitely on the new app model in all my webapp2 code :).

Comment: I might run some tests on my instance with big images.  Mine aren't in the 10 mb range as I am serving them from the data store and that limit is 1 mb

Comment: You could always try calling gc.collect at some point.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate you testing with images in the 6-10MB range. I'm pretty shocked at the performance here. In my production code I had littered with it gc.collect() and tried reusing variables assigned to big objects in memory as a hack to no avail. I'll try setting the variable to None and running gc.collect() and report what happens.

Comment: Running gc.collect() seems to have no effect.

Comment: Removed webapp code since it didn't add any additional useful information.

Comment: Ok I did a test using bobo.  I uploaded 6 x 5MB images.  On instance startup memory use was 21MB.  After the first upload memory went to 27MB, after that it peaked at 48.6MB no matter how many times I have uploaded the image. I have a single instance running, it started up clean for the test. In addition my code does a little bit more on each upload - it creates a MultiDict from the resquest object.  I have no calls to gc.collect()  Let me know if you want to see the code.

Comment: Oh I can't do lots of uploads my net connection is 3G, if you would like to upload larger and more files to the instance let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still seeing this -- I'm on a ~10mb/s up connection though making the calls in rapid succession.

Comment: Do you want to run some tests against my instance ? If the problem is not present on my instance, then we can narrow it down to something you are doing, or specifically something about webapp[2]

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem using webapp2. My instances keep dying from memory errors: `Exceeded soft private memory limit` too. I am also trying to upload files to Cloud Storage though. I am going to try using your code, without the GCS stuff, to see if I can reproduce the problem with only webapp2.

Comment: Which version of python?  What version of what OS (I am not familiar with F1 or F2)

Comment: This question is for Google App Engine, where you don't control OS, you only control instance class of machines. F1s are slower CPUs and less memory while F4s are faster CPUs and more memory.

Comment: ANyone know how to upload  an rotated image to blobstore? I have rotated an already saved image using `images.Image.rotate` function. BUt don't know how to save back..

Comment: We could not find a solution for our memory issues while uploading large files using F1 instances (128MB). After speaking with Google Support, it was suggested we use better instance class machines. We changed our `app.yaml` file to specify `instance_class: F4` and I have been running that for 2 days without errors. The memory does spike high occasionally but always falls back down eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Blobstore for your images? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob

Comment: I'm trying to send back a thumbnail of the image to show to the user in the uploader client when it was successfully uploaded. Creating the thumbnail in JS uses a ton of RAM and this seems like something I should be returning from the server.

Comment: I do the same in my projects, via ajax usually. But I think your problem is that you're trying to upload image to 'regular' servers and not to the servers that are specially optimized for media upload, like Blobstore and Cloud Storage, for example. Look at the example on page I linked, it's simple procedure. You can also look into images API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages#Uploading

Comment: I second using the BlobstoreAPI as it's very simple and has always worked for me. I think it's a good fit for your use case, @robertfischer . 
You can still have the images stored in Google Cloud Storage as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage).